# transfer php variables from one server to another

Tags: php

I have a contact form which post the input to a .php file located in my server. 
some of the code:

```
$name_field = $_POST['name'];
$email_field = $_POST['email'];
$phone_field = $_POST['phone'];
$message_field = $_POST['message'];
```

In my server I can't use php mail(), so I want to transfer this variables to another .php file located in other domain.

I know I can do it directly in the form

```
action="http://otherdomain.com/contact.php"
```

but I want the php script to be on my server and "Behind the scenes" transfer the variables.
My first question is if it possible to do so in this way? and the second, how to...

Comment: You could always make the action a php page on your own server, then pass from there to the other domain.

Comment: yes, this is what i want. how to do this?

Comment: `fsockopen();` <3 `curl_*();` <3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to use CURL

```
$url = 'http://www.otherdomain.com/contact.php';
$fields_string = http_build_query($_POST);

//open connection
$ch = curl_init();

//set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($_POST));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

//execute post
$result = curl_exec($ch);

//close connection
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using `CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE` ?

Answer (score 2):

You can send the post request using `file_get_contents()` (for example) :

```
// example data
$data = array(
   'foo'=>'bar',
   'baz'=>'boom',
);

// build post body
$body = http_build_query($data); // foo=bar&baz=boom

// options, headers and body for the request
$opts = array(
  'http'=>array(
    'method'=>"POST",
    'header'=>"Accept-language: en\r\n",
    'data' => $body
  )
);

// create request context
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

// do request    
$response = file_get_contents('http://other.server/', false, $context)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the for some reason the form input is empty

Comment: how can i check where is the problem? the email received empty

Answer (score 0):

```
    *Here is the code to send data from one domain to another using curl in php*     `$url='http://training3.mbincbs.com/karma/phpcontact.php';
$s = curl_init();
curl_setopt($s,CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,

        "contactmessage=".$message."&contactname=".$name."&contactemail=".$email."&contactsubject=".$subject);

curl_setopt($s, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
```

echo $server_output = curl_exec($s);
curl_close($s);

*phpcontact.php*

```
`$Name = $_POST["contactname"];
`$Email = $_POST["contactemail"];
`$Subject = $_POST["contactsubject"];
`$Message = $_POST["contactmessage"];
```

if(isset($link)){

$sql="INSERT INTO Contact (contactname,contactemail,contactsubject, contactmessage) VALUES ('$Name','$Email','$Subject', '$Message')";
  $res=mysqli_query($link,$sql);