# How to send data via PHP from one server to another

Tags: php, mysql, webserver, private-network

Is it possible to send data via PHP from one webserver on a private network to another webserver on the WWW?

The private network only allows traffic on port 80 and 8080.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can function across servers yes. How you implement it and how you ensure security is down to your method. Simplest way to get results would be `POST`.

In simple answer to your question... Yes, it is possible.

As for a method, take a look at this: [transfer php variables from one server to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17618484/transfer-php-variables-from-one-server-to-another)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is Possible,You can send your form data to remote server using `CuRL`.